# Convert unsigned apk into signed apk

Tags: java, android, apk

I have an android application with un-signed package, Whenever I try to install this apk, following error message throws `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]`.

Now I want to insert my keystore certifcate with this apk file. is there any possibilities to do this with external command rather than IDE?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to automatically sign you project app with android studio or use an external command tp sign just an apk file?

Comment: @VishnuPrabhu read my post clearly.

Comment: @Médéric Thanks for your clarification I want this in external command. I have answered to my own question.

Comment: @sathish : Thanks for clarifying me and posing the answer. Will help many

Comment: This can be a valid scenario. I don't understand why so many downvotes.

Answer (score 15):

We can do this via jarsigner tool comes with the JDK

**Steps**

In Windows

**Step 1:** set path **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin`** in command line

**Step 2:** **`jarsigner -verbose -keystore /path_to_keystore/keystoreFileName  /path_to_apk_file/application_name.apk keystoreFileName_alias`**

-keystoreFileName_alias. You have to provide your alias name of your keystore file name.

**Step 3:** Enter password of your keystore file

**Step 4:** Completed. It will displays warning messages like certifaction validity etc..

**Step 5:** Verify your apk file `jarsigner -verify /path_to_apk_file/application_name.apk`

**Zip align:**

**Step 6:** set path **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W`** in command line

**Step 7:** **`zipalign -v 4 /path_to_apk_file/application_name.apk /path_to_destination_apk_locaion/zipped_application_name.apk`**

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

your forgot to add zalign, which aligns your files and helps memory. Please update your answer